# GraphQL client in .Net with subscription

Tags: c#, .net, client, graphql

couldn't find any .Net client for GraphQL that has support for subscription
am I missing something really obvious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an expermiental subscriptions support in this library:

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client

You need to use prerelease versions of this package.

like explain in this issue:

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client/issues/61